# Sort "Master-Detail" DataGridView bound to Entity Framework in Winforms

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, sorting, datagridview, master-detail

I'm writing a small business application in C#, .NET 4.0. I am using SQL Server CE 4.0 as my database.

I use Entity Framework to communicate in both directions with database. My datagridviews are bound to Entity Framework collection, thus user can add new or modify existing data directly in datagridview. The problem is that sorting with Entity Framework bound to datagridview is not really supported. From what I have learned:

1. I can **intercept clicks to column header cells** and then perform sorting and rebind result to datagridview. It is a bit tedious, but it works for master datagridview. But when I do that also for "detail" datagridview" then I loose the automatic rebinding of "detail" datagridviews (when new row from master table is selected). So I have to deal with that also.
2. I can **cast query to a list / binding list and pass it to a sortable bindinglist**. Well here I have the same problem with rebinding "detail" datagridviews manually. The new problem that here arises is, that now I have to somehow fix saving, because new data is added only to the sortable bindinglist and not directly to the Entity Framework context.

What should I do (and how)? Should I just use DataSets?

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to use an intermediate [observable]collection which holds the sorted entities.  However this is in the WPF/MVVM world.  And even then the Pattern is still relatively the same for ASP.NET ObjectDataSource or MVC using Collections.  It's been quite some time but maybe I can brain dump a bit where hopefully you can find something useful.

I'm pulling this from memory so bare in mind this is nothing more to help point you in some direction.

Form variables we'll use.

```
private string SortProperty { get; set; }
private ListSortDirection SortDirection { get; set; }
private ICollection<myItems> items; // Entity Collection
private ObservableCollection<myItems> SortedItems { get; set; } // Sorted Collection
```

Overload the form OnLoad event handler to register a header clicked handler to apply sorting.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick);

    LoadDataGridView();
    base.OnLoad(e);
}

protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick -= new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick);
    base.OnUnload(e);
}
```

Perform our initial load of the sorted data.

```
private void LoadDataGridView()
{
    items = myRepository.GetAllItems(); // However you get or have your collection of items.
    ApplySort();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = SortedItems;
}
```

Sort our data and save in new collection.  The OrderBy requires Dynamic Query Library: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx.

```
private void ApplySort()
{
    // IQueryable<myItems>, ICollection<myItems>, ObservableCollection<myItems>... be aware of cross threading and how you will handle updates.
    SortedItems = items.AsQuerable().OrderBy(SortProperty + (SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? " asc" : " desc")).ToList();

}
```

Our click event handler.  Remember, you will have to handle entities added, deleted and changed.

```
private void dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    var propertyName = GetPropertyName(dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex])
    SortDirection = SortProperty == propertyName ?
            SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending ? ListSortDirection.Descending : ListSortDirection.Ascending
        : SortDirection;
    SortProperty = propertyName;
    ApplySort();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = SortedItems;
}
```

Trivial helper method for sorting.

```
private string GetPropertyName(int columnNumber)
{
    switch(columnNumber)
    {
        case 0:
            return "Id";
        case 1:
            return "Name";
        default:
            return "Id";
    }
}
```

Here is some additional information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171608.aspx

I know this isn't an exact answer but since no one else will chime in, maybe you can take this, hack it up until it works gracefully and then comment your solution for the next person.